# Flutter: How to navigate page by clicking Text

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to click to the Text and navigate page. But when i press to the Text , nothing happens.

Heres my code :

```
 Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignIn.id);
                            });
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "Sign In",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
```

Heres main.dart :

```
class WoxisApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: Welcome.id,
      routes: {
        Welcome.id: (context) => Welcome(),
        SignIn.id: (context) => SignIn(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Text with a `GestureDetector`:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {   whatever you want    },
  child: Text( your text widget ),
}
```

Comment: I did. Nothing happens when i press to the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the  name of the route.

`Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignIn.id)` is saying, go to the route `SignIn.id`. I don't know if that is an enum or a variable. And your routes are defined as :

````
{
        Welcome.id: (context) => Welcome(),
        SignIn.id: (context) => SignIn(),
}
    ```

I'm guessing that the problem is that `SignIn.id` is a variable, and the value it evaluates too is different in each of those locations. So it will never find the route.

I would check that the values match.
````

Comment: I replaced the ontap like = print("adfafsda") and nothing happens again.